# Positioning background-image in CSS

Tags: html, image, css

I need to use CSS' `background-image` to display an image in a `div`, but there is also a requirement of having to position the `background-image` just a little bit (maybe 1 or 2%) to the left (equiv. of `margin-left: -2%;`).

I'm unsure of how to do this. I did have a look at `background-position`, but it does not seem to be what I'm after.

How can I position a `div`'s `background-image` in CSS?

An example is shown below. The gray block is the `div`, and the blue circle is the `background-image`. Normally, this circle would just be at the top-left of the div. But I need to be able to adjust its position, even though it's a `background-image` and not your typical `<img />` element.

[image]

How can I do this?

Comment: Have you try `background-position`?

Comment: @IqbalFauzi Thanks, I did mention in my question that I had tried `background-position`, but my IDE kept giving me red squiggles when I used it so I thought I wasn't meant to use it that way.

Comment: OP said he had, not sure why it wasn't right for him however.

Comment: Can you post the actual code you're using? A jsFiddle too perhaps?

Comment: I think it may be just a bug in Visual Studio (maybe). I just looked up the specs for `background-position` (which I should have thought of before asking here) and apparently I can use it to do what I want: http://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS/Properties/background-position

Comment: hey check this Fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/NRXtz/2/ hope it helps...

Comment: I second @j08691, we need something more than that to work with.

Comment: Thank you @dippas, that works perfectly. I'll stick around to accept if you want to make it an answer.

Comment: I'll make it right now ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So as suggested by OP I'm making my comment into an answer.

Here is a **[Solution](http://jsfiddle.net/NRXtz/2)** for your problem

using `background-position`